# what is the difference between political system and government?

Tags: constitution, government

I want to know

what   is   the   difference    between    political     system   and    government ?

Comment: The word "government" simply has several distinct meanings in English. It can mean the cabinet, the whole state apparatus, or the way the political process is organised. It can therefore come close to being essentially synonymous with "political system" or have a different meaning entirely.

Comment: @Relaxed to add to this, there is also ["government" as it is used in social theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Governmentality) where it has a more general meaning referring to (not necessarily political) means of control.

Answer (score 3):

A Government is an entity that governs a certain group of people. One of its main distinguishing features is the monopoly on the legal use of force.

A Political System is a general set of principles, ideals and limitations that are followed by a government regardless of the more specific goals of that particular government.

For example, we can say that even though the Democrat and Republican parties have vastly different goals, they both follow the general outline of Democracy as a political system when they're in control of the government(this is oversimplifying it of course, but I think it's not necessary to go into detail).

Comment: Can you offer any citations or additional background on these definitions?

Answer (score 0):

Political system represent the entire idea of statecraft whereas the constitution as a significant and specific limited concept under political system.

Comment: Welcome to Politics.SE. You may need to expand your answer, providing with more details on each statement. Also, some quotations and links to credible sources would be helpful. Otherwise, the entire answer rather looks like an opinionated comment and may attract downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

The government may be defined in two ways: 1) Collective body of a state's executive power; 2) All bodies of a state (sometimes - local bodies of the states or other subjects of a federation as in the case of the USA) power;
A political system is a concept introduced in Political science by David Easton in 1950-s. It is connected with some social relations and interactions and participants of both latter. All of them deal with authoritative allocation of goods in society. Not state alone is part of the political system. Political parties, voters, etc. also are  elements of the latter.